# How Can i access object given inside the startup.cs from an Xunit project in .net core?

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, xunit.net

> I was trying to unit test my .net core application, but I was not able to establish the connection, on calling from an angular application it is working but when I tried that from a Xunit project it is returning an unAuthorized result.

```
 var _glassClient = new HttpClient();

        _glassClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:17290");
        _glassClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
          new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var cookieTokenString = "dfdfdfdtrhghfguytuyiyuoyuof.gfjgfjfyiyijhgjdfgsdtaedgdfbghfyu";

        _glassClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", $@"{cookieTokenString}");

        var httpResponse =  _glassClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:17290/api/widgets/SummaryApi");
      var responseContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I have tried the above code but that it is throwing an unAuthorized exception

is there is any way to access the below code from the startup.cs

```
 services.AddSingleton(x =>
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            //TODO: Should read this from config
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:29490");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
              new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            return client;
        });
```